# Django and Flutter wth http Plugin

Tags: django, flutter, django-rest-framework, flutter-http

I've created a REST API with Django and I want to use it in Fluter. I've created the endpoints and tested them; they work fine, I've also created the models in flutter. I've done the get all endpoint. I'm now struggling with how to decode the details endpoint and use it in Flutter.

Anyone's thoughts ?

Comment: Take a look at Flutter docs: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-manually-using-dartconvert.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the response from API, you can use `json.decode` to convert the body of your request from a string to a json, and then you can parse the json to your model, like the example below:

```dart
// Model Example
class Model {
  final String name;

  Model.fromJson(dynamic json)
    : name = json['name'];
}

...
// Do the request, receive a [response]
final body = response.body;
final jsonBody = json.decode(body);
final model = Model.fromJson(jsonBody);
```

If you want a more detailed example, please send a piece of your code and I can explain based on your context

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what are you using if you are using [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http/example) package this is an example

```
import 'dart:convert' as convert;

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  // This example uses the Google Books API to search for books about http.
  // https://developers.google.com/books/docs/overview
  var url =
      Uri.https('www.googleapis.com', '/books/v1/volumes', {'q': '{http}'});

  // Await the http get response, then decode the json-formatted response.
  var response = await http.get(url);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var jsonResponse =
        convert.jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    var itemCount = jsonResponse['totalItems'];
    print('Number of books about http: $itemCount.');
  } else {
    print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.');
  }
}
```

if you are using Dio package you don't need to decode [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) will do it for you this is an example

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

void getHttp() async {
  try {
    var response = await Dio().get('http://www.google.com');
    print(response);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```